# Print a php page with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, echo

I use Ajax a lot to pass JSON data but I have actually a problem.

I would like to transfert the php of my page to a other page and only print it with ajax.

Php:

```
<ul  class="thumbnails biblio sortable">
                                <?php
                                    $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT id_gallery,nom_gallery,link_gallery,img_gallery
                                    FROM gallery where id_gallery='$gallery'");


                                    $donnees = $reponse->fetchAll();
                                    for($k=0;$k<count($donnees);$k++){
                                        $id_gallery=$donnees[$k]['id_gallery'];
                                        $nom_gallery=$donnees[$k]['nom_gallery'];
                                        $link_gallery=$donnees[$k]['link_gallery'];
                                        $img_gallery=$donnees[$k]['img_gallery'];

                                        $link_gallery = explode(",", $link_gallery);

                                        $longueur=count($link_gallery);
                                        //echo "longueur: ".$longueur;
                                        for($j=0;$j<$longueur;$j++){
                                            $id=$link_gallery[$j];
                                            $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT nom_fichier,id_fichier
                                                                    FROM fichier
                                                                    where id_fichier = '$id' ");


                                            $donnees = $reponse->fetchAll();
                                            if(count($donnees) != 0){
                                                $nom_fichier=$donnees[0]['nom_fichier'];
                                                $id_fichier=$donnees[0]['id_fichier'];

                                                if($j % 4 == 0 && $j !=0){
                                                    echo"</ul>";
                                                    echo"<ul  class='thumbnails biblio sortable'>";
                                                }
                                                //if($)
                                                echo"<li class='span3 ui-state-default info' style='overflow:hidden;' data-click='".$id_fichier."'>";
                                                //str+="<input id='"+data[i].id_gallery +"' type='checkbox' value='option'>";
                                                echo"<ul class='thumbnail-actions'>";
                                                echo"<li><a href='#' title='Edit photo'><span class='icon-pencil'></span></a></li>";
                                                //str+="<li><a href='upload/download.php?filename="+dataSplited[i].nom_fichier+"' title='Download photo'><span class='icon-download'></span></a></li>";
                                                echo"<li><a class='delete' id='href-".$id_fichier."' href='".$nom_fichier."' data-click='".$id_fichier."'  title='Delete photo'><span class='icon-trash'></span></a></li>";
                                                echo"</ul>";
                                                echo"<a class='thumbnail' href='#' ><img alt='Image 34' src='upload/uploads/".$nom_fichier."' style='width:200px;height:200px;'  ></a>";
                                                echo"</li>";
                                                }

                                        }



                                    }
                                ?>
                            </ul>
```

The problem is that i don't know how to print all the "echo".

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/demo.html#page1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to print output of your above code in other page, just simply use `.load();` method. http://api.jquery.com/load/ it same with php `include()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this Script to load from another page. I have tried with this its working 
      
     var default_content="";

```
  $("#pageContent").onClick(function loadPage(url)
  {
url=url.replace('#page','');

$('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourPHP.php",
    data: 'page='+url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
            $('#pageContent').html(msg);
            $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    }

});

   }
 </script>
 <div id ="pageContent">
......do something  here
 </div>
```